# Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup extremely slow when primary server goes offline

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013

I am performing some failover tests with 2 Exchange servers in a stretched DAG cluster and a witness server in AWS. So far the automated failover process is working quite flawlessly. However, when the main datacenter Exchange server is suddenly disconnected, Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup command issued to the secondary server's Exchange Management Shell takes minutes to return. I can't seem to pinpoint what's causing this lag. If connectivity to the primary Exchange server is restored, slowness of Exchange Management Shell is then immediately goes away. The strange part is also if the reverse happens and the secondary Exchange server was holding PAM and mailbox roles, and it is disconnected, the symptoms does not appear on the primary Exchange server that picks up the roles.